# Touch screen not responding

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 4 with a 7 inch HDMI touch screen display. The display works fine but I can't find any docs for getting the touch screen to work.

Comment: what is the model of the touch screen? Did it come in a kit? Also what OS did you put onto your Pi? Touch screens aren't inherently compatible with all Pi OS distributions, so you may need 3rd party software.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea what the model number is. I got it from walmart.com and the label on the box is written entirely in Chinese. I did Google and found instructions on how to get the display to work but no details on the touch screen component. I assume it's a knockoff of some brand name thing but I am not finding anything.

Comment: can you please open a terminal and type the command ```which --version``` and let us know what OS you're using? You may not have a touch screen driver.

Comment: Odd but which didn't work. Anyway, it's raspbian 10 (buster).

Comment: So Raspbian DOES support touch screen but you have to set it up through the DSI port not the HDMI port

Comment: This display is odd. It has 2 USB ports, one labeled power and the other touch. After reading the doc I have, one powers the display and the other is the touch screen. But, from reading the doc, it seems you can use one cable for both. I have tried it with both one and two cables and it doesn't work. I

Comment: can you maybe edit your question by uploading pictures of all the ports on the screen? I may be able to help you further

Comment: I just started using the app and can't figure out how to upload the photo. In any case, there are just 3 ports on the board, two micro USB and one HDMI.

Comment: to add a photo it's just ```ctrl+G``` but if it's just an HDMI and two micro-usb ports I do not believe it is compatible afaik

Comment: I had hoped that there would be a driver or configuration to make it look like a mouse. Also, I'm doing this on a phone and I have no idea how to type control g. I don't even know if apps understand control characters. Something else to Google 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but since you're using Raspbian 10 a touch screen will not work through the HDMI port, instead you need a touch screen that will connect to the DSI port. There is an official Raspberry Pi touch screen that will work with this port straight out of the box.